# Enabling UART TTY for an RK3128 Embedded Linux Device

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, u-boot, tty, rockchip

**Background**

I have an embedded Android device device that uses the *U-Boot* bootloader. The system also uses the *Busybox* suite.

I have access to the *U-Boot* shell through a UART port and can dump, modify, and upload a new filesystem but I have no terminal access to the OS. One limitation I have with *U-Boot* is that the `saveenv` command has been disabled however, the `setenv` command seems to work for the current boot session.

The `bootargs` U-Boot variable is currently set to `storagemedia=nand` (there is no `console=` setting).

So far I have tried using `echo` on various serial ports and modifying the **inittab** file to setup a TTY shell for the UART port.

My attempts to setup a TTY shell

```sh
::respawn:/sbin/getty -L serial 115200 -n -l /bin/autologin
::respawn:/sbin/getty -L serial0 115200 -n -l /bin/autologin
::respawn:/sbin/getty -L s0 115200 -n -l /bin/autologin
::respawn:/sbin/getty -L console 115200 -n -l /bin/autologin
```

The original Line in the **inittab** file (doesn't work)

```sh
# [THE ORIGINAL LINE]
ttyFIQ0::respawn:/sbin/getty -L  ttyFIQ0 0 vt100 #
```

Regardless of what I do, the last few lines I receive from the UART port are:

```
## Booting Android Image at 0x62ce3248 ...                                      
Kernel load addr 0x62ce3a48 size 4400 KiB                                       
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 61f00000                                       
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x61f00000                                     
   XIP Kernel Image ... OK                                                      
CACHE: Misaligned operation at range [62ce3a48, 6312f888]                       
   Loading Device Tree to 60ff1000, end 60fff36c ... OK                         
Adding bank: 0x60000000 - 0x61000000 (size: 0x01000000)                         
Adding bank: 0x61200000 - 0x70000000 (size: 0x0ee00000)                         
                                                                                
Starting kernel ...
```

After the `Starting kernel ...` message, I receive nothing indicating that a TTY shell is running even though, the OS boots and runs perfectly. If I type anything into the terminal after the `Starting kernel ...` message has been received, the OS freezes.

**Question**

How do I setup a TTY shell for the Operating System that will use the UART port so that I can finally interact with the embedded device OS through a terminal?

Comment: Please edit the question to indicate the model of the processor and add the appropriate tag for that chip.

Comment: "*After the `Starting kernel` ... message, ...*" - That message is from U-Boot. You seem to be asking the wrong questions. What indication is there that the kernel actually boots successfully? Perhaps there are no terminals with any shell simply because the kernel has not booted successfully??? Perhaps you need to reconsider your choice of "*no `console=` setting*" in the `bootargs` variable (assuming the kernel has been configured to support a serial or network console). You might even need to use **earlycon** or **earlyprintk** to learn what is going on.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the OS is successfully loaded after the "Starting kernel ..." message and the device functions normally. Does this mean that the kernel was successful? Thank you for the tip with earlyprintk and earlycon, I'll try to get those running.

Comment: So far modifying earlycon and earlyprintk has done nothing. I noticed that environment variables "stdin", "stdout" and "stderr" are set to "serial" and changing this value will partially disable the terminal. Maybe I could configure "earlycon" and "earlyprintk" to use this same "serial"? Setting "earlyprintk=serial earlycon=serial" did not work. If it helps, I think I found this serial device in the "dm tree" output, listed as serial0@20060000 as an ns16550_serial device.

Comment: "*So far modifying earlycon and earlyprintk ...*" - Whatever random things you're doing seems like wild guessing. "*My attempts to setup a TTY shell ...*" - Unless it's a customized kernel, you have not specified any terminal name that is likely to exist (except for `console`). The convention for  naming device nodes for a serial terminal has the form `ttySn`, such as `ttyS0` or `ttyS1`.

Comment: Sadly, I had already tried the `ttySN` options (for example, `earlycon=ttyS0`) with 0-4 as N values however none of them had any effect. (Not sure if this should be in a separate post) Is the `20060000` attached to the device name `serial0@20060000` the hex address for the device, and if so, could I pass this hex address to `earlyprintk` like so `earlyprintk=serial,0x20060000,115200` ([uboot doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) I pulled this format from)? When I tried this two newline characters were received however everything else was the same.

Comment: That is not what I was suggesting; **earlycon** or **earlyprintk** have additional configuration requirements. The likeliest chance of success is with the **inittab** or the `console=` setting in the bootargs variable.

Comment: Where can I find information regarding additional **earlycon** and **earlyprintk** setup requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I couldn't establish a shell connection on the **UART0** port was because the **UART0** port was being used by the **fiq-debugger** which prevented me from starting a `getty` program on the **UART0** port through device `ttyFIQ0`. After looking around the **.dtb** file (in the `Flattened Device Tree blob at 61f00000`), I noticed that serial devices (named something like `serial@20060000`) had their status set to `status = disabled`.

I modified the `.dtb` file to enable all of the serial ports (set their status to `status = okay`. Then, I also had to modify the `serial-id` property of the `fiq-debugger` in the **.dtb** file to be a value other than `0x00` since `0x00` refers to **UART0** which is the only accessible UART port on circuit board I was using.

Finally, I modified the *inittab* file on the device to run a `getty` program on port **ttyS0** (this device was originally disabled in the **.dtb** file). With that final change, the **RK3128** allowed a serial terminal on **UART0**.